# Matrix multiplication using numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, regression

I am trying to do a linear regression using Matrix multiplication.

`X` is the feature matrix, and I have 100 data points. As per the normal equation, the dot product of `X` and of the transpose of `X` is required.

Having added a column of ones as required, the shape of `X` is `100×2` while for the transpose of `X` it is `2×100`.

However, when I am doing the dot product, the result (which is given in the book) comes accordingly, a `2×2` matrix. Shouldn't it be a `100×100` matrix as per laws of matrix multiplication using dot product?

Conceptually, where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are feeding them in the wrong order

Instead of feeding `(100,2) * (2,100)`, you are feeding `(2,100) * (100,2)`

Comment: Oh my god. That was so very inattentive of me. Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: @JOYBHOWMIK Joy, if the answer solved your problem, on this site it's deemed good manners to accept it

Comment: @gboffi Accepted as an answer! Stackoverflow has a cooling period after which an answer can be accepted hence the delay! Regards!